# warning: already initialized constant PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, wicked-pdf, rails-3-upgrade

Right now I am working on rails 3.0.0. If I run my project in terminal, I get this warning. Please help me.

/usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:98: warning: already initialized constant PDF

Comment: You might look in environment.rb to see if you have a PDF mime-type listed twice

Comment: Are you using a PDF library such as Prawn?

Comment: are you using Wicked PDF? https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/pull/82

Answer (score 62):

You might have this in your `config/initializers/mime_types.rb` file.

```
Mime::Type.register 'application/pdf', :pdf
```

It looks like newer versions of rails already registers it.

Comment: are you sure that rails registers it by default now?

Comment: No i'm not sure. It could also be caused by other gems registering it as well.

Comment: Yes, sure, it was added on 2011-06-27 in this commit https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d73269ba53992d8a01e5721aad3d23bc2b11dc4f

Comment: I had a similar problem. Even though I wasn't registering the :pdf mime type myself, one of the gems I was using was too old and still doing that. When I upgraded the gem to a later version, the error disappeared. If you can't find the source code, likely one of your gems is the culprit.

Comment: @AminAriana I had similar case but decided to solve it with re-registering the mime-type. For that I did `Mime::Type.unregister(:csv)` at first in mime-types initializer and after that registered csv-type again with desired new attributes.

Answer (score 29):

Try using [`lookup_by_extenstion`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/Mime/Type/lookup_by_extension/class) before defining it.

I have this on my `config/initializers/mime_types.rb` file.

```
Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf unless Mime::Type.lookup_by_extension(:pdf)
```

Comment: May not be necessary, but it's safer. Thanks!

Comment: I was having the same error in Rails 3.2.14 using the Prawn gem.  Changing `Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf` to `Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf unless Mime::Type.lookup_by_extension(:pdf)` did the trick!  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. This helped me.

Comment: Simply removing the `Mime::Type.register 'application/pdf', :pdf` gave me errors, but `Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf unless Mime::Type.lookup_by_extension(:pdf)` did the trick

Comment: You might want to extend that a bit to make sure the previous registration is actually identical to the one you are making:  Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf unless Mime::Type.lookup_by_extension(:pdf) == "application/pdf"